# Use ApplicationContext if possible in Android?

Tags: android, applicationcontext, android-context

Is it a good practice to use application context instead of other context(Activity, Service and so on) if possible? 
Pros:

1. Application context can help us avoid memory leak.
2. Application context can help eliminate params in some circumstances
3. Other things don't come to my head for now

Cons:

No clue for me after googling for a while and this is where this question from.

Comment: Refer the so question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to use application context instead of other context(Activity, Service and so on) if possible?

Not in general. Use `Application` when you know **precisely why** you are using `Application`.

> Application context can help us avoid memory leak.

It can also cause memory leaks (creating a custom subclass of `Application` and storing things in there). It can also screw up your UI (by ignoring themes), screw up the back stack, etc.

> Application context can help eliminate params in some circumstances

I have no idea what you mean by that, sorry.

[This blog post by Dave Smith](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) provides an excellent overview of different types of `Context` and their roles.

Comment: Application context can help eliminate params in some circumstances: It happens when I want access to resouces such as strings or drawables in a helper class. I don't have to pass an Activity instance to it if using Application Singleton.